# "between close contacts" and "during close contacts"

Tags: prepositions

https://youtu.be/1APwq1df6Mw?t=30

In the above video, the following is said.

> This is the reason person to person spread is happening mainly **between close contacts**.

I thought **between close contacts** means time intervals between a close contact and another one. Such as, "I had a close contact with a person. After that, I got virus somewhere. Then I had a close contact with another person."

Is it right to say **during close contacts** instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From watching the whole video, the sense is that transmission is more likely between those who are physically close to each other, say, closer than 1 meter. So, that's what they mean by "between close contacts": between people who are close to each other. They are not referring to the time elapsed between multiple contacts.

I agree that "during close contacts" would be a better way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is poorly worded. What they apparently mean is, "... between people in close contact." Note in context they are saying that you have to be within 1 meter of the other person for the virus to spread this way.

"Contact" can be used to refer to a person with whom you have contact, like, "My contacts include Bob, Sally, and Mary." So I briefly thought that they meant "people with whom you have close contact", like, "My close contacts are Bob, Sally, and Mary." But that doesn't really make sense here, as if you say that a person is a "close contact" you mean that they are someone you know very well, not someone that you stand physically close to when you meet.

Comment: Thank you. The another meaning of "contact" is informative. It is a little funny to imagine the virus spreads along social relationships.